# best algo to track an object in an AVI video, with opencv in c++

Tags: algorithm, object, opencv, video, tracking

I would like to track a target in video AVI I made, I run a lukas Kanade algo I found on internet and it's not doing what I whant because it follow every point moving in the record. 
Do you know if there is an algo in open source whith wich I can select my target with an ROI and track in each frame ?
(I use opencv 2.4.6 with Visual studio 2013)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [OpenTLD algorithm by Zdenek Kalal](http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/Z.Kalal/tld.html). Here is [original MatLAB implementation](https://github.com/zk00006/OpenTLD) and [port to the C++](http://gnebehay.github.io/OpenTLD/) .

Comment: Thank you old-ufo, I will try it this week-end and give you a feed back.

Answer (score 3):

I don't fully understand what you are looking for but here is a quite good list of OpenCV tracking methods: http://www.intorobotics.com/how-to-detect-and-track-object-with-opencv/

For simple usage of ROI check the answer to this question: [Understanding region of interest in openCV 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705817/understanding-region-of-interest-in-opencv-2-4)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. First I would like to follow the center of my target which is moving slowly, so I would like to select it in the video and follow it. If I succeed it, I would like to get the number x, y of the target move and then convert it in distance, but I'm not already here.